# Using Perfmon with MySQL Connector/NET

Tags: asp.net, mysql, performance, perfmon, mysql-connector

I am trying to diagnose repeated lock wait timeouts from my ASP.NET app to MySQL 5.1. I'm using MySQL Connector/NET 6.2.3.

I don't see anything MySQL-related in Perfmon's Performance Object dropdown list.

What else can I do to try to diagnose these issues?

Comment: I would also love to know the answer to this question.  Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: I never found out but there is a newer version of the driver I have not yet tried.